# Inventor of null hypothesis significance testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references, history

NHST is universally most used method of scientific inferencing. When was it first described in its current form and when was it first time used in the medical research? This info seems to be hard to find.

Edit. More spesifically, what was the first time when the following NHST procedure was used in the field of medicine:

1) Set null hypothesis (group means are equal) and alternative one (group not equal)
2) Calculate p-value for H0
3) If p is below preset cut-off (0.05), then reject null and state that there is a difference. If not below, then don't reject and conclude something else.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "in its current form". Do you mean Neyman-Pearson style, specifically? (though formally, that might exclude all those people using p-values rather than an explicit rejection rule based on the test statistic)...  Are the tests Fisher was doing both before and after that okay? (even though he tended to avoid explicit alternatives?) Or Student? What about Pearson's chi-squared test? What about Arbuthnot's use of the sign test? What *exactly* counts as "in its current form" and what doesn't? (wherever you do draw the line, why draw it there?)

Comment: I'm really not clear on exactly which things must be present (or perhaps not present) for it to count. I don't think you will reasonably succeed in being able to name any single person as "the" inventor, since the ideas build up over time. When you look at Pearson's paper on the chi-square goodness of fit test, in his examples he does calculate a test statistic and even what corresponds to a p-value but a lot of the framework you might expect to see in a hypothesis test isn't clearly laid out.

Comment: Question edited